# How to update the progress bar in DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am new to .Net and I want to know how I can update the progress bar when I click on the Download Button in a particular row on the DataGrid. Since there's limited sources that address this I don't understand how to achieve this.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="servers" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="148" Margin="0,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="clientPreview" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" 
                                    Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar 
                            Value="{Binding Progress}"
                            Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button  Background="#FF00FF35" Click="beginDownload">Download</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**The Generated DataGrid Looks like this :**

[image]

**The BeginDownload Method Looks like this :**

```
private void beginDownload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clients selected = servers.SelectedItem as Clients;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            if (selected.Id == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected Feild is Empty", Title = "Empty Feild Selected");
            }
            else
            {
                //Update Progess Bar and Other Methods

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Field is Empty", Title = "Empty Field Selected");
        }
    }
```

I only want to know how I can update the progess bar in a particular row. For example if I put a for loop and update the progress from 0 to 100. How to bind the integer value to the progress bar?

Found a Similar problem with no answers -[Wpf Datagrid change element in the same row on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443527/wpf-datagrid-change-element-in-the-same-row-on-click)

Comment: What is your Clients type.. has it public property Progress ? How you run Download.. in UI thread or as a async Task ? Probably you need to update it from the method which actually perform Download.

Comment: clients is a public class and progress is a public property. When you click on Download button is will trigger the above method beginDownload. I got the progress bar to work Ill post my solution. However I need help with slowing the speed of the progress bar. Please help with that

Comment: @Anthon any solution for my current problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WPF very popular **MVVM** approach with command pattern.
Accordingly to it.. you need to have **View** and **ViewModel**.. then you will be able to use command for the Download button in your grid and pass parameter to it.

```
public class ClientsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
   public DelegateCommand DownloadCommand {get; private set;}

   // ctor
   public ClientsVM() 
   {
        DownloadCommand  = new DelegateCommand(DownloadExecute));
   }

   // async method allow to not block UI thread 
   public async void DownloadExecute(object param)
   {
       var client = param as Clients;
       if (client==null) return;

       // TODO: call real code for download 
       for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
       {
          await Task.Delay(100); // slow changes of progress
          client.Progress = i;   // if setter of Progress raised NotifyPropertyChanged.. it will update ProgressBar in your DataGrid
       }      
   }
}
```

For use your DownloadCommand just bind it to the property of Button

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="servers" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="148" Margin="0,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="clientPreview">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" 
                                    Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar 
                            Value="{Binding Progress}"
                            Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button  Background="#FF00FF35" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Download</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution in Page.xaml.cs:**

```
Visual vis;
private void beginDownload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Clients selected = servers.SelectedItem as Clients;
    if (selected != null)
    {
        if (selected.Id == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Feild is Empty", Title = "Empty Feild Selected");
        }
        else
        {
            for (vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
                    if (vis is DataGridRow) //Find current DataGridRow
                    {
                        ProgressChanged();
                        //Other methods
                        break;
                    }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Field is Empty", Title = "Empty Field Selected");
    }
}
private void ProgressChanged()
    {
        // Update the progressbar percentage 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            ((Clients)(((DataGridRow)vis).Item)).Progress = i;
        }
    }
```

**My Clients Class :**

```
public class Clients : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int mProgress;
    public Clients()
    {
        Id = 0;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return mProgress; }
        set
        {
            mProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**I have one more issue my progress bar speed is too fast, How can I slow down the progress bar speed?**